# GAE - Instances seem to die and return 502 rather than elegantly deploy

Tags: php, google-app-engine

We're using GAE to deploy our new PHP code. Every time we use the command

`gcloud --quiet --project project-id app deploy --no-promote --version=v4 app-prod.yaml cron.yaml`

The deployment works fine, however during the deployment process, it seems to shutdown all the available GAE instances rather than rollout the deployment 1 by 1. We're presented with the 502 - Bad gateway error whilst deployments are happening.

We've tried adding readiness and liveness checks; we've tried adding automatic scaling properties. We're still getting 502s during deployment.

Our app.yaml configuration file:

```
runtime: php
env: flex
runtime_config:
  document_root: public
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 4
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 3.6
# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
  - .env
env_variables:

network:
  instance_tag: no-ip
  name: default

readiness_check:
  path: "/api"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

Comment: It is hard to debug this kind of errors once inside of GAE, therefore I would like you to provide me if possible with a stacktrace or even the full logs where do you see the 502 errors, bearing in mind that it could possibly contain sensitive data, therefore it should be sanitized before uploading to this post. Furthermore, I see you are using automatic_scaling and I have seen similar issues when not having [warmup_request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/configuring-warmup-requests)  can affect greatly the performance of your instances.

Comment: As a consequence, could you please try to add warmup request and try deploying your Google App Engine application again? This would help me narrow down the issue, and as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling_min_instances) when using min_instances property, you should enable warmup_request. I hope it helps